# How to clone a xib and viewcontroller quickly?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I am going create a new xib which is very similar to an existing one. Instead on of crate an blank new one, copy UI elements and viewcontroller IOOutlets; is there a quick way to clone a xib with corresponding new viewcontroller class?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go the Finder and duplicate the xib file. Open it up in IB and wire up the File Owner to a new view controller class.